# How to calculate the area between two Excel charts?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two Excel charts:

[image: Two Charts]

How do I calculate area between these?

Answer (score 2):

There's not such function built in as far as I know, but it's quite easy to perform a trapezoid integration on the data. Se [here](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~haggertr/487/integrate.htm) for example.
I suggest you calculate the area for series 1 and series 2 and then subtract the two results.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment. Also, I don't understand why you removed "calculate integral" from the question which better explains what the user wants to do.
In this particular example the area of the trapezoid is numerically equal to the average because the x spacing is 1, but this is not true in general.

Comment: Of course there is a value for the integral of series 1 from 1 to 3. I don't know what the user wants to do with the data but if he wants the  area strictly between the two series he should start calculating the integrals from the point x=3.